# Android - Frames and LoadURL

Tags: javascript, android, webview, frames

I've search relentlessly for this and I still can't find a solution.

First things first; I'd like to retrieve data from a frame in the router's info page for a DSL-2750.

Now, I've been trying to use the following code, which works in the browser console but comes back as undefined in the error log for my debugging.

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:frames['main'].document.getElementById('infstatus0').innerHTML");
```

I've tried different variations on this with frames[1], parent.frames[1] and parent.frames['main']. The results always comes back the same; "Cannot read property 'document' of undefined."

Now, secondly. I'm trying to read the value from the javascript so I've tried the following.

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

@JavascriptInterface
public void onData(String value) {
        tv.setText(value);
        if (value.equals("Connected")){
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else if (value.equals("Connecting...")){
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }
```

I'll be moving the setText into the if statement when it works. But it appears that throughout all my navigating and everything, the value of the textView isn't changing. I would suspect that executing any java code through loadURL would trigger the onData wouldn't it? Maybe I should just try the console.log trick.

Comment: So I've updated to 4.4.2 so that I can use webview.evaluateJavascript. Which is nice since I can now at least get some feedback from the javascript that I'm executing. But it appears as if the command frames[] is not retrieving anything in the webview. I'm trying to find a different solution now.

Comment: So it would seem that the reason this problem occurs is that the so called "main frame" is not the frame that is named main where I require my information from. And it would appear that onPageFinished is only triggered for the "main frame" itself. So my javascript is trying to execute before the required frame has finished loading. Now the question is how am I going to get it to wait until the load is complete.

Comment: You won't believe this. After struggling with this damn thing forever. document.getElementById('infstatus0').innerHTML works in 4.4.2. WHY?!